# parse json data with pyspark

Tags: json, pyspark

I am using pyspark to read the json file below :

```
{
  "data": {
    "indicatr": {
      "indicatr": {
        "id": "5c9e41e4884db700desdaad8"}}}}
```

I wrote the following python code :

```
from pyspark.sql import Window, DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
schema  = StructType([
  StructField("data", StructType([
    StructField("indicatr", StructType([
       StructField("indicatr", StructType([
         StructField("id", StringType())

         ]))]))]))])

df = spark.read.json("pathtofile/test.json", multiLine=True)
df.show()

df2 = df.withColumn("json", F.col("data").cast("string"))

df3=df2.select(F.col("json"))
df3.collect()


df4 =df3.select(F.from_json(F.col("json"), schema).alias("name"))
df4.show()
```

I am getting the following result :

```
|name|
+----+
|null|
```

Anyone who knows how to solve this, please

Answer (score 0):

When you select the column labeled `json`, you’re selecting a column that is entirely of the `StringType` (logically, because you’re casting it to that type). Even though it looks like a valid JSON object, it’s really just a string. `df2.data` does not have that issue though:

```py
In [2]: df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- indicatr: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- indicatr: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: double (nullable = true)
 |-- json: string (nullable = true)
```

By the way, you can immediately pass in the schema on read:

```py
In [3]: df = spark.read.json("data.json", multiLine=True, schema=schema)
   ...: df.printSchema()
   ...: 
   ...: 
root
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- indicatr: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- indicatr: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
```

You can dig down in the columns to reach the nested values:

```py
In [4]: df.select(df.data.indicatr.indicatr.id).show()
+-------------------------+
|data.indicatr.indicatr.id|
+-------------------------+
| 5c9e41e4884db700desdaad8|
+-------------------------+
```